# How can I get the selected column rows on top first and then the remaining rows that do not belong to the selected column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to sort rows according to categories. Let me explain with example.
Lets assume i have a following rows.

```
Id        Title       Cat_id              
1          ABC         3         
2          BAC         4   
3          DBC         5
4          ---         3 
5          ---         2 
6          ---         7 
7          ---         1 
8          ---         2 
9          ---         6 
10         ---         8 
11         ---         9
12         ---         10
13         ---         12 
14         ---         5
15         ---         3
```

So, now i want to show cat_id 3 and 2 posts on top and then other cat_id's posts.

Expected result is

```
Id
1
4
5
8
15
2
3
6
7
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

Comment: Would you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need conditional order by clause like

```
select *
from demo
order by Cat_id in(3,2) desc, Id
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b159cf/4)

Comment: Thanks For Reply.

I want to follow that situation with pagination also.